# SQL query to update table

Tags: sql

Might be stupid example but curious to know how we can do it with SQL query. I am using MySQL but trying to write query db independent way.

I have following table,

```
Course
---------
Id | lang    | batch | flag
===========================
1  | Java    |  A    | null
2  | Cpp     |  B    | null
3  | Java    |  A    | null
4  | Java    |  C    | null
5  | Java    |  C    | null
```

Query is, if two records found for lang = Java with same batch then set flag = 0 for first entry and set flag = 1 for second entry in table.

So output for above query would look like following,

```
Course
---------
Id | lang    | batch | flag
===========================
1  | Java    |  A    | 0
2  | Cpp     |  B    | null
3  | Java    |  A    | 1
4  | Java    |  C    | 0
5  | Java    |  C    | 1
```

How I can write SQL query for above example. Thanks for help :)

**EDIT :**
Sorry for late edit,  there is one addition like if there is only one record found for lang = java and any batch then set flag to 0.
Is it possible to write both queries in single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work correctly assuming that a given matching batch will only have two records:

```
UPDATE Course t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT batch
    FROM Course
    GROUP BY batch
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN lang = 'Java' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.batch = t2.batch
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT batch, MIN(Id) AS minId
    FROM Course
    GROUP BY batch
) t3
    ON t2.batch = t3.batch
SET t1.flag = CASE WHEN t1.Id = t3.minId THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Note: The above Fiddle does a `SELECT` to show which records would be updated, and what the old and new flag values would be for each record.

The exact `JOIN` syntax you would need to use is database-specific.  I gave the syntax for MySQL, but the query should not change much in going to another RDBMS such as SQL Server, so long as it supports join updates.

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE for create row number and update based on CTE to physical table :

```
CREATE TABLE #Course(Id INT,lang VARCHAR(100), batch VARCHAR(10),flag INT)
INSERT INTO #Course(Id ,lang , batch ,flag )
SELECT 1  ,'Java','A'    , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2  ,'Cpp','B'    , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3  ,'Java','A'    , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 4  ,'Java','C'    , NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 5  ,'Java','C'    , NULL

;WITH CTE AS
( 
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY batch ORDER BY Id) RNo , lang    
 ,batch,Id FROM #Course
)
UPDATE #Course SET flag = CASE WHEN RNo = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM CTE 
WHERE #Course.Id = CTE.Id 

SELECT * FROM #Course
```

Answer (score 0):

with 2 updates:

First:

```
update Course set flag = 0 where Id in (select min(id) from Course C where
Lang = 'Java' group by lang, batch);
```

Second:

```
update Course set flag = 1 where lang = 'Java' and flag is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do it by using CASE with sub query:

```
update c set c.flag = case when c.id = t.id then 1 else 0 end
from #Course c
inner join (select max(id) id, lang, batch 
            from #Course 
            group by lang, batch having count(id)>1) t on c.lang = t.lang
and t.batch = c.batch
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PostgreSQL-tested version:

```
UPDATE
Course
SET
flag = CASE WHEN t2.min = Course.Id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
(SELECT
Course.batch,
MIN(Course.Id)
FROM
Course
WHERE
Course.lang = 'Java'
GROUP BY
Course.batch
HAVING COUNT(Course.batch) = 2) AS t2
WHERE
Course.batch = t2.batch
```